Is a particular person meant in 'I can't pretend to be much of a judge of poetry, I'm an English teacher, not a homosexual.'?
Does the speaker here humorously refer to some particular homosexuals who tried to present themselves as self-styled 'judges of poetry'? If so, who is this person or who are these people?
'It's about this poem, really. I've read it, Terry. I can't pretend to be much of a judge of poetry, I'm an English teacher, not a homosexual. I have to say that it worried me.'
From 'A Bit of Fry and Laurie', 'Prize Poem'.

I assume he's referring to himself (in real life).

Presumably it's poking fun at the idea that it was 'effeminate' for a man to be interested in the arts.

Might be worth mentioning that 'A Bit of Fry and Laurie' was a comedy sketch show from the late 1980s and early 1990s. I'd imagine that the reference to homosexuals pandered to the idea that they were more in touch with their femine side and, therefore, would appreciate poetry more.

@KillingTime In other words, no particular homosexuals prior to 1980 were widely known to be 'judges of poetry'?

I doubt that the reference was to any particular individual.

I’m voting to close this question because this is off-topic. Asking what literary critics were gay doesn't belong here; at a push it would go on Literature SE.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about the English language.

Please explain your contexts better.

This question is more about the overall setting in which the utterance is made than about the utterance itself (the meanings of the words used in it are all obvious, and the grammatical structure is unremarkable).

It's a joke, as the OP noted. The person speaking is a rather stuffy English teacher who says they're not much of a judge (an expert) when it comes to poetry.
But they should be, that's part of their job, to help interpret and teach poetry to school children.

“I'm an English teacher, not a homosexual. I have to say that it worried me.”

Stephen Fry is a declared homosexual, he will often joke about his sexuality, and the audience would have been in on the joke because it was ironic, and a lie.
In this scene,  Fry plays the role of an English teacher who succumbs to the trope that homosexuals are particularly sensitive people who are into the arts; painters, dancers, singers, and readers of poetry. The teacher is worried about the student's well-being because their poem is about despair and self-loathing; in stark contrast to the themes of 19th century English poetry.
The student's poem contains the lines: "I asked for answers and got a headful of heroin." "My body disgusts, damp grease wafts sweat balls from sweat balls and thigh fungus", "When time fell wanking to the floor, they kicked his teeth" and "fireball the dead cities of the mind and watch the skin peel and warp." Fry asks Laurie,

I mean, why can't you write about meadows or something?

to which Laurie replies laconically

I've never seen a meadow.

Script

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
